# Decrypting PGP using gnupg in Python

Tags: python, pgp

I am trying to decrypt a PGP file using this module:
http://packages.python.org/python-gnupg/

Here is my code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gnupg

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='C:\\Users\\GSquire\\Desktop\\GnuPG',
                                gpgbinary='C:\\Users\\GSquire\\Desktop\\GnuPG\\pub\\gpg.exe',
                                keyring='C:\\Users\\GSquire\\Desktop\\GnuPG\\secring.skr')

with open('.\\tranx08022012.txt.pgp', 'rb') as f:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase='passphrase', output='out.txt')
```

I am using the latest version of the module, and Python 2.6.6. I thought I could just use the secure ring file to decrypt it because that is obviously needed by the file.  It outputs this when I run the script:

```
ok: False
status:
stderr:
gpg: expected public key but found secret key - must stop
```

Isn't it true that the secure key is what decrypts the file?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not if the file was encrypted with the secret key; GPG encryption is asymmetric, if you encrypt with one key, you can only decrypt with the other. That can be either the public or private key.

Comment: I have actually successfully encrypted with the public key, I guess I was just double checking.

Comment: My understanding (and I may be wrong, because I'm not an expert *at all* in encryption) is that is usually considered a not-too-good practice decrypting with public keys. I don't know if that is always true, though. Usually (at least with RSA encryption) you encrypt with public, decrypt with private (although you sign with private and verify signatures with public) Mmm... I may need to ask this myself...

Comment: I am trying to use the private key.  I should have pointed that out.  I didn't think it would be such a headache trying to do this!

Comment: Perhaps I get this wrong because I am new to this as well but this is how I understand it. The idea behind a pair of public and private keys is you share your public key. Everyone who has your public key encrypts files. Only the owner of a private key can successfully decrypt files. Signing is done by a private key because only one person should sign a file and everyone else should verify a signature using a public key. I don't know why using pair of keys is not recommended. The only issue with signature and verification is that you must first trust the sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you're passing the secret keyring's filename in the `keyring` parameter. That parameter is only for the public keyring. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an alternative parameter to specify a secret keyring file.

By default, GnuPG will look for secret keys in `secring.gpg` in the `gnupghome` folder you specify, so you can probably rename your secret key file and get it to work.

Comment: I tried copying the secret ring and public ring.  It didn't complain about not finding the secret key but now it says Invalid cipher algorithm.  It is encrypted with a 1024 bit RSA key and an IDEA algorithm.  I feel like I am out of luck!

Comment: GnuPG doesn't support IDEA by default due to patent issues. See http://www.gnupg.org/faq/why-not-idea.en.html for details (and a workaround, if the patent doesn't apply to you).

Comment: Well, I'll have to try that when I'm back at work.  Thanks for the lead.  I am glad I AM only using it for decrypting like it says on the page.